# How to find Visual Studio's web server's application pool mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, iis

When I run my website in visual studio 2010, it works.
When I deploy it in IIS, it doesn't work.

Can I find the settings of visual studio's web server?  That will be really helpful for learning purpose for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on ASP.NET Development Server or even IIS Express (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/).

A long time ASP.NET developer should understand that playing with IIS as early as possible is the correct way.

Show the exact errors that your application reports (on IIS), and then someone can tell you what's up. It is useless to learn more about ASP.NET Development Server as your application is not finally deployed on it.

Comment: I would have considered this extreme until I ran into some problems (e.g. requests using the HTTP PUT method) with the Development Server web server recently.

Answer (score 1):

Use real IIS, lots of stuff is different in integrated mode.  If you do httpmodules, you will find anything but real IIS doesn't support stuff like adding headers and such.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio 2010 development web server is an entirely .NET based server.  As such it has much more in common with the intergrated pipeline of IIS7 than it does with the Classic.   It doesn't support all that the IIS7 integerated pipeline does since it only has to concern itself with delivering .NET and static content and doesn't need the optomisations that IIS7 will employ.

Comment: So in theory, am I right in saying that if a website can run under VS web server then it should run under IIS 7 Integrated mode because the services that VS webserver offer is a subset of services that IIS 7 integrated mode offers? The reason for asking is because sometimes a website only runs under classic mode and under VS web server but does not run under integrated mode.  This confuses me.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: There is no reason I can think of why a typical ASP.NET web site should not be able to run under the IIS 7 integrated mode.  That would be the prefered and target configuration.  You would have to be using something unusual like a third-party ISAPI Filter to warrant not using integrated mode.  Perhaps you should define "it doesn't work" better?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the recently-released IIS Express.  It's MUCH closer to full IIS, but has all the quick debugging goodness of Cassini (the APS.NET Development Server).  Then you can develop on that (it has many of the same options - not sure about app pool, though) and have greater confidence that things will be the same as on full IIS.

Comment: @Austin:  I wouldn't recommend that.  When developing the developement server is much easier to do debugging with.  When testing deployment you want to test on all the real platforms that you'll be deploying to.  The most likely issue here is one of configuration, its highly unlikely that the code is somehow incompatible with integrated mode.

Comment: @Anthony - sure, what I meant is test locally with IIS Express, but of course make sure full IIS is good in some kind of staging environment if you can.  Still, I think IIS Express largely makes Cassini obsolete.

Comment: If you are going to deploy your applications onto IIS, play with it as soon as possible. Neither ASP.NET Development Server(Cassini), nor IIS Express comes closer to the real IIS.